# Multiple Query run N1QL couchbase with nodejs error out-of-memory condition

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

I want to migrated data MySQL to Couchbase.

I have imported company with _id=UUID.

Now I want to import other data which it related to company. I need _id of company in to new Import But When I run N1Ql Query in a loop to find it related data it show error as below.

```
Error: An unknown N1QL error occured. This is usually related to an 
out-of-memory condition
```

what I am doing. 
First get other data then use for loop to run N1QL query to get it related data. This time the error occured. I am Using **Nodejs**

**when I put the limit 0,200 it's work but it more then 300 it is given this error**

Comment: Can you share code? be more precise?

Comment: first **Select * from Users**.
then I put it into for loop for every user I run N1QL query in Nodejs. when I use this query only for 200 user it will work but then it will give error.

Comment: if you do the select * without any couchbase operations, can you get all of your results? of you also get OOM exception?

Comment: see if i use **Select * from Users limit 0,200;** it is ok. it will run also 200 times N1QL query.
But when I use **without limit** there is 1000 result. so it will give error to run 1000 N1QL query

Comment: have you really checked the memory footprint? and as I asked. please share the entire code in your question.

Comment: I get the solution by creating Index

Comment: Which index btw? I assumed that you already have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the exact N1QL query, sample document, and your code.
Can you check what errors/warnings you have in query.log. Also, provide your h/w setup and couchbase cluster setup details. How many documents are in the bucket, and avg size of the docs?

-Prasad